# Implementation question involving implementing an interface

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, implementation

I'm writing a set of collection classes for different types of Trees. I'm doing this as a learning exercise and I'm also hoping it turns out to be something useful. I really want to do this the right way and so I've been reading [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) and I've also been looking at the way Joshua Bloch implemented the collection classes by looking at the source. I seem to have a fair idea of what is being done, but I still have a few things to sort out.

I have a `Node<T>` interface and an `AbstractNode<T>` class that implements the `Node` interface. I then created a `GenericNode<T>` (a node that can have 0 to *n* children, and that is part of an *n*-ary tree) class that extends `AbstractNode<T>` and implements `Node<T>`. This part was easy.

Next, I created a `Tree<T>` interface and an `AbstractTree<T>` class that implements the `Tree<T>` interface. After that, I started writing a `GenericTree<T>` class that extends `AbstractTree<T>` and implements `Tree<T>`. This is where I started having problems.

As far as the design is concerned, a `GenericTree<T>` can only consist of nodes of type `GenericTreeNode<T>`. This includes the root. In my `Tree<T>` interface I have:

```
public interface Tree<T> {

    void setRoot(Node<T> root);

    Node<T> getRoot();

    List<Node<T>> postOrder();

    ... rest omitted ...
}
```

And, `AbstractTree<T>` implements this interface:

```
public abstract class AbstractTree<T> implements Tree<T> {

    protected Node<T> root;

    protected AbstractTree() {
    }

    protected AbstractTree(Node<T> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public void setRoot(Node<T> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public Node<T> getRoot() {
        return this.root;
    }

    ... rest omitted ...
}
```

In `GenericTree<T>`, I can have:

```
public GenericTree(Node<T> root) {
   super(root);
}
```

But what this means is that you can create a generic tree using any subtype of `Node<T>`. You can also set the root of a tree to any subtype of `Node<T>`. I want to be able to restrict the type of the node to the type of the tree that it can represent. To fix this, I can do this:

```
public GenericTree(GenericNode<T> root) {
   super(root);
}
```

However, `setRoot` still accepts a parameter of type `Node<T>`. Which means a user can still create a tree with the wrong type of root node. How do I enforce this constraint? The only way I can think of doing is either:

- Do an `instanceof` which limits the check to runtime. I'm not a huge fan of this.
- Remove `setRoot` from the interface and have the base class implement this method. This means that it is not part of the contract and anyone who wants to make a new type of tree needs to remember to implement this method.

Is there a better way?

The second question I have concerns the return type of `postOrder` which is `List<Node<T>>`. This means that if a user is operating on a `GenericTree<T>` object and calls `postOrder`, he or she receives a list that consists of `Node<T>` objects. This means when iterating through (using a foreach construct) they would have perform an explicit cast to `GenericNode<T>` if they want to use methods that are only defined in that class. I don't like having to place this burden on the user. What are my options in this case? I can only think of removing the method from the interface and have the subclass implement this method making sure that it returns a list of appropriate subtype of `Node<T>`. However, this once again removes it from the contract and it's anyone who wants to create a new type of tree has to remember to implement this method. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you sure that you need `setRoot` method at all? I remember one advice from Effective Java is to `favor immutability`.

Comment: @Alexander That is true. It's actually another idea I've been thinking about - whether `setRoot` is really necessary. I'm starting to lean towards it *not* being necessary. What about the second question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you putting a cart before a horse.

Implement a couple of concrete instances of `Tree<T>` and `Node<T>`.  Only after that analyze what implementation they have in common and only after that implement your `Abstract` classes if they still make sense at that point.

**EDIT**

To answer your second question:

If simple `Node<T>` does not cut it in your `Tree` interface, then you have no choice, but to declare a second parameter to generic interface and put a boundary on it, like this

```
public interface Tree<
  T,
  TNode extends Node< T >
>
{

    void setRoot(TNode root);

    TNode getRoot();

    List<TNode> postOrder();

    ... rest omitted ...
}
```

Then AbstractTree

```
public abstract class AbstractTree<
  T,
  TNode extends Node< T >
> implements Tree<T, TNode> {

  protected TNode root;

  protected AbstractTree(TNode root) {
    this.root = root;
  }

  ...
}
```

Then GenericTree

```
public class GenericTree< T >
  extends AbstractTree< T, GenericNode< T > >
{

  public GenericTree ( GenericNode< T > root )
  {
    super( root );
  }

  @Override
  public List< GenericNode< T > > postOrder ( )
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's what I did first actually, and I identified the common methods that are implementation-independent. All I've got left are the cases I talk about above - namely trying to figure out how to return the list of nodes.